How to compare a file on disk with a file from a different branch which does not exist on disk
I want to perform a comparison operation between a file which exists on disk and a file which no longer exists because I moved it.
Here's the situation.

I had a file which existed in a folder. Let's call it ./src/A.txt.
I moved A.txt to a new folder. It's now called ./doc/A.txt.
I edited ./doc/A.txt.

I now want to compare ./doc/A.txt with the state of ./src/A.txt which exists on the branch origin/main. Of course, this file does not actually exist in the current working directory.
I think one possible way to do this might be to do the following:

git checkout origin/main ./src/A.txt
git diff ./src/A.txt ./doc/A.txt

(Edit: Nope - this doesn't work. Use diff ./src/A.txt ./doc/A.txt instead.)
Is there a way to do it "directly"?
Maybe something like
git diff ./src/A.txt@origin/main ./doc/A.txt


you were close, the syntax to point at "a file or directory inside a commit" is: <commit>:<path>

part of the dense doc page git help gitrevision

@LeGEC thanks - for some reason I thought @ was involved in there somewhere... maybe because of HEAD@... ? I can't remember what this relates to though

see git help gitrevision ;)

You can get what you want with:
git show origin/main:./src/A.txt | diff - doc/A.txt

or
git diff origin/main:./src/A.txt doc/A.txt

